# Insert decimal input into CRM 365

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, crm, decimalformat, dynamics-365

I'm working with CRM REST Builder to build my requests.
I'm creating a web resource from it, I'm inserting a record with Decimal input.
when entering a number from decimal input, this error is displayed:

> Cannot convert a value to target type 'Edm.Decimal' because of conflict between input format string/number and parameter 'IEEE754Compatible' false/true.

Please help.

Comment: It might help to post the request....

Answer (score 9):

I found that when submitting a json message to CRM Rest API, if the value is a string it gives me this error.

```
{ unitprice : "1234.00" }
```

You need to convert it to a number before hand so that it resolves like this:

```
{ unitprice : 1234.00 }
```

Comment: tip: use a fiddler. In the composer try to find which field is incorrect, by taking off the field sent. After that try to send the field, taking off the double quotes.